# How to show snapshot API response data in data-studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-api, looker-studio

I need to design and display a **compute engine snapshot** report for different projects in the cloud in data-studio.  For this, I am trying to use the below Google Compute Engine snapshot-api for retrieving data.

**https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/snapshots**

The data may change everyday depending on the snapshots created from the disks. So the report should display all the updated data.

Can this rest-api be called directly from Google data-studio?

Alternatively, what is the best/simplest way to display the response in data-studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/)  in Data Studio to directly pull the data from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, their is no way to connect GCP Compute Engine (GCE) resource data or use the REST API in Data Studio. The only products that are available on connecting data from GCP are the following:

1. BigQuery
2. Cloud Spanner
3. Cloud SQL for MySQL
4. Google Cloud Storage
5. MySQL
6. PostgreSQL

A possible way to design and display a Compute Engine Snapshot Report for different projects in the Cloud in Data Studio is by creating a Google App Script (to call the [snapshot REST API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/snapshots/list)) with a Google Sheet, and then import the data into the sheet on Data Studio.

Additionally, if you have any questions in regards to Data Studio, I would suggest reviewing the following documents below:

- [Data Studio Help Center](https://support.google.com/datastudio/#topic=6267740)
- [Data Studio Help Community](https://support.google.com/datastudio/community?hl=en)

**EDIT**: My apologies, it seems that their is a way to show snapshot API response data in Data Studio by using a [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/) to directly pull the data from the API.

Comment: One can use Community Connectors to fetch data from REST API in Data Studio. Ref: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/.